# React-Native Push Notifications with Laravel Echo Server

Tags: laravel, react-native, mobile, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I managed to setup a real-time connection using *Laravel Echo Server + Redis* on my *React-Native* application. Is there a way to setup a Push Notification for both Android and IOS system without using third party services like FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging)?

Comment: You can use FCM for push notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But there is a way to do it without using FCM or any other third party service?